# How to parse many variables to bash?

Tags: bash, scripting

A program outputs its data in this format:

```
n=4607356
null_cells=5668556
cells=10275912
min=0.0433306089835241
max=0.53108499199152
range=0.487754383007996
mean=0.40320252333736
mean_of_abs=0.40320252333736
stddev=0.0456556814489487
variance=0.00208444124856788
coeff_var=11.3232628285782
sum=1857697.565113524
first_quartile=0.378443
median=0.410276
third_quartile=0.435232
percentile_90=0.457641
```

And I want parse some of those variables into bash so I can use them into my script eg:

```
$n = 4607356
$median = 0.410276
```

and so on, in one go.

How can I do that?

Comment: Those are a lot of variables, are you sure that writing a small Python (or pick your favorite scripting language) would not be an easier way to deal with all this data?

Comment: @Levon maybe his favorite language is `bash` :)

Comment: @rush touché .. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems the easiest way is to redirect output to a file and then to source this file.

In script it will look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
program > tmp_file
. tmp_file
rm tmp_file
echo $any_var_you_need
```

In `bash` you can do it without temporary file at all:

```
#!/bin/bash
source <(program)
echo $any_var_you_need
```

The only theoreticall security hole is that program may output some dangerous code that will destroy something.

You can avoid it with checking `program`'s output with `sed` to be sure it contents only variables:

```
program | sed '/^\s*[a-zA-Z_.][_a-zA-Z0-9]*=[a-zA-Z0-9_-+.,]*/!d;s/ .*//;'
```

it will remove all strings that seems like not variables (may be edited at your taste).

Comment: This is a terrible plan. It is not a theoretical security hole, it is a massive and very real security crater.

Answer (score 2):

With the same security caveat as @rush mentioned, you could simply prepend `eval` to your command. Of course, in both cases, anything that isn't valid bash syntax will produce an error (that you can ignore).

Example:

```
$ echo 'a=1
> b=2
> c=1234'
a=1
b=2
c=1234
$ echo $b

$ eval echo 'a=1
b=2
c=1234'
a=1
$ echo $b
2
```

Comment: Just `eval 'a=100 ...'` (without the `echo`) works as well

Comment: Of course, I was emulating the output of his program there.